# What is an algorithm to split N line segments into M segments (N <= M) in a balanced way?

Tags: algorithm

Perhaps a trivial question but I'm looking for an algorithm that can split N line segments into M segments (M >= N) in a balanced way (e.g. that the R^2 r-squared is maximized). Anyone has a good reference?

**EDIT** (added example as requested by commenters):

For example, lets have `N = 5` segments with lengths: `{1, 10, 7, 15, 1}` which we want to split into `M = 7` parts.

- A good solution would be: `{1, 1, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8}`  (split 15 and 10)
- A bad solution would be: `{1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 7, 10}`  (split 15 into 3)

I guess, a greedy algorithm with `distance from avg` as a heuristic could do well but wasn't sure whether there are some corner cases with it.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you provide an expected input - output pair? The problem is unclear. The way you stated it, it seems that you always get the same sum of lengths of all M segments, because splitting does not change the sum of lengths.

Comment: Hi Bartosz, thanks for the comment. I thought about the balanced way, so let say minimize sum(avg-length(segment)). I'm just wondering whether there is an optimal algorithm (a proven one). Cheers

Comment: How do you degine "split N line segments into M segments", care to provide a simple example? It sounds that unless I am completely misunderstanding you, there is an NP-Hard problem here with reduction from K-Partition Problem and/or binpacking problem.

Comment: This is NP-Hard as @amit mentions.

Comment: @Ivaylo, Amit: do you know any good approximate algorithms to attack the problem?

Comment: "so let say minimize sum(avg-length(segment))" I think this is the same problem. This is sum(avg) - sum(lengths), which is 0.
Did you want to add a square somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem in fact is *not* NP-hard, because it is not possible to recombine the pieces. Here's an O(m log n)-time algorithm for the problem of determining cuts to minimize the sum of the squares of the lengths of the resulting pieces. Initialize the split count on each of the segments to one and put them in a priority queue (I'll specify the priorities shortly). Repeat the following action m - n times: pull the topmost segment (maximum priority), increase its split count, and put it back into the queue.

The priority of each segment is the sum of squares of its current division minus the sum of squares of its hypothetical division into one more piece. For example, if 15 is currently split into two pieces, 7 and 8, and we could split it into three, 5, 5, and 5, then the priority is 7^2 + 8^2 - 5^2 - 5^2 - 5^2 = 38. To work your example, the initial priority queue is

```
15 (1 cut), priority 15^2 - 7^2 - 8^2 = 112
10 (1 cut), priority 10^2 - 5^2 - 5^2 =  50
 7 (1 cut), priority  7^2 - 3^2 - 4^2 =  24
 1 (1 cut), priority  1^2 - 0^2 - 1^2 =   0
 1 (1 cut), priority  1^2 - 0^2 - 1^2 =   0.
```

We split 15 one more time.

```
10 (1 cut ), priority 10^2       - 5^2 - 5^2       = 50
15 (2 cuts), priority  7^2 + 8^2 - 5^2 - 5^2 - 5^2 = 38
 7 (1 cut ), priority  7^2       - 3^2 - 4^2       = 24
 1 (1 cut ), priority  1^2       - 0^2 - 1^2       =  0
 1 (1 cut ), priority  1^2       - 0^2 - 1^2       =  0.
```

We split 10 one more time.

```
15 (2 cuts), priority 7^2 + 8^2 - 5^2 - 5^2 - 5^2 = 38
10 (2 cuts), priority 5^2 + 5^2 - 3^2 - 3^2 - 4^2 = 16
 7 (1 cut ), priority 7^2       - 3^2 - 4^2       = 24
 1 (1 cut ), priority 1^2       - 0^2 - 1^2       =  0
 1 (1 cut ), priority 1^2       - 0^2 - 1^2       =  0.
```

We stop here; 15 would be next up, for 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7.

The reason that this "greedy" algorithm is optimal is because the returns from splitting a segment into more pieces are independent and diminishing in a precise technical sense (supermodularity).

Comment: Brilliant! Works as a breeze. Many thanks David! Regarding complexity, could you clarify why O(MlogN). I think you need to sort the initial N segments and that gives O(NlogN) and then do O(M-N) moves. Am I right?

Comment: @Jacek It's OK to sort initially, but the priority of a segment changes each time it's reinserted, hence M - N priority queue operations on a queue of size N. If speed is critical, I could probably figure out how to reduce the time complexity at the cost of implementation complexity.

Comment: Yes, now I see it. Many thanks again. No, please don't worry about the time complexity it was just an academic question ;-). You've already helped a lot. Cheers,